# Forem - Layout doesn't recognize routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forem

I'm new with `forem` gem. I want to set the same layout for my application and my forum.

I changed the default `config/initializers/forem.rb` to set my `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` layout :

```
Rails.application.config.to_prepare do
  Forem::ApplicationController.layout "application"
end
```

**I get this error :**

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `start_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000008fb00d8>:0x00000008f5ec10>):
```

... some more informations of my configuration :

- This layout contains this line :

  `<%= link_to("Start", start_path) %>`
- My `config/routes` contains this line :

  `get 'start' => 'statics#start', :as => :start`
- And a `rake routes | grep start` returns this :

  `start GET /start(.:format) statics#start`
- The layout works perfectly ouf of `forem` pages.

Do you have any idea of the problem ?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I auto-answered for next readers.

I must set paths like this :

```
main_app.start_path
```

And voilà !

Comment: Is there a workaround? If there are many paths in the shared layout, adding `main_app` manually to all of them will be time-consuming and error-prone.